# Inner merge in python with tables having duplicate values in key column

Tags: python-3.x

I am struggling to replicate sas(another programming language) inner merge in python .
The python inner merge is not matching with sas inner merge when duplicate key values are coming .

Below is an example :

```
zw = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
                "Name":['Shivansh','Shivansh','Shivansh','Amar','Arpit','Ranjeet','Priyanka'],
                "job_profile":['DataS','SWD','DataA','DataA','AndroidD','PythonD','fullstac'],
                "salary":[22,15,10,9,16,18,22],
                "city":['noida','bangalore','hyderabad','noida','pune','gurugram','bangalore'],
                "ant":[10,15,15,10,16,17,18]})


zw1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID-":[1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
                    "Name":['Shivansh','Shivansh','Swati','Amar','Arpit','Ranjeet','Priyanka'],
                    "job_profile_":['DataS','SWD','DataA','DataA','AndroidD','PythonD','fullstac'],
                    "salary_":[2,15,10,9,16,18,22],
                    "city_":['noida','kochi','hyderabad','noida','pune','gurugram','bangalore'],
                    "ant_":[1,15,15,10,16,17,18]})
```

zw and sw1 are the input tables . Both the tables need to be inner merged on the key column Name .The issue is both columns are having duplicate values in Name column .
Python is generating all possible combinations with the duplicate rows .

Below is the expected output :
[image: expected output]

I tried normal inner merge and tried dropping duplicate row with ID and Name columns , but still not getting the desired output .

```
df1=pd.merge(zw,zw1,on=['Name'],how='inner')

df1.drop_duplicates(['Name','ID'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) + [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) combination:

```
df = zw.combine_first(zw1).sort_values('Name')
print(df)
```

---

```
   ID  ID-      Name  ant  ant_       city      city_ job_profile  \
3   1    1      Amar   10    10      noida      noida       DataA   
4   0    0     Arpit   16    16       pune       pune    AndroidD   
6   1    1  Priyanka   18    18  bangalore  bangalore    fullstac   
5   0    0   Ranjeet   17    17   gurugram   gurugram     PythonD   
0   1    1  Shivansh   10     1      noida      noida       DataS   
1   0    0  Shivansh   15    15  bangalore      kochi         SWD   
2   0    0  Shivansh   15    15  hyderabad  hyderabad       DataA   

  job_profile_  salary  salary_  
3        DataA       9        9  
4     AndroidD      16       16  
6     fullstac      22       22  
5      PythonD      18       18  
0        DataS      22        2  
1          SWD      15       15  
2        DataA      10       10
```